# PHP Multidimensional Array from cURL

Tags: php, csv, curl

I am trying to export the results from querying "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv" with PHP and cURL.

I am using the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&     c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv");
curl_setopt ($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$data=ob_get_clean();
$data=explode(",",$data);
$data=str_replace('"','',$data);
foreach ($data as $results)
{
echo "<td>$results</td>";
}

?>
```

How can show the results in Table format just like they appear in "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv" ??

I doing something wrong in echo ...  but I am not sure how to do it.

Yours

Comment: you're trying to dump table cells without a `<table>` or even `<html><body>` to wrap it all in. If you want something formatted in a certain way, YOU have to write the code to make that formatting happen.

Comment: I wrote the code and wrap the results with <table>, <tr>, <td> but again I do not manage to get it properly displayed as it is in http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    ob_start();
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data = ob_get_clean();

    $rows = explode("\n", $data);
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    foreach($rows as $row) {
      echo "<tr>";
      $cols = explode(',', $row);
      foreach($cols as $col)
        echo "<td>$col</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Comment: No problem, do you have any idea how can I create a chart out of it?

Comment: This (http://www.pchart.net) is one I have used for charts. It is quite simple to use (http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.basic.syntax.html)

Comment: It will help me a lot if you could tell me how to access just one cell's content. I am trying echo $rows[0][0]; but it only takes the letter D.